# jdk src file won't unzip

Tags: java, file, zip, unzip

In my JDK file the zip file called "src" won't unzip. It's located in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60". When I try to unzip it, I get an error that says, "Compressed (zipped) Folders were unable to create the specified directory. Ensure that the directory does not already exist, and that the path entry is valid." I know that the path entry is valid, so how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you want that??? --- Anyway, you might be running into an OS limitation on longest path name. Try unzipping to `C:\src`. --- Better yet, use an IDE that can display the JDK source, with *color coding*.

Comment: @Andreas He want to see the source code. So he can learn ? And I just try that, no path name problem.

Comment: @FerdinandNeman I think you hit the real problem, with the permission issue. But if OP wants to learn from the JDK source code, he should use an IDE (e.g. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)), which will color code the source, allow navigation, lookup by name, and a lot of other goodies.

Comment: @Andreas How he learn is out of the context of the question, be it with IDE or not. Don't get me wrong, your tip surely helpful, but out of context. His question is asking on how to extract the zip file, and lets answer his question.

Comment: @FerdinandNeman I think it's a good idea to offer alternatives (when appropriate), rather than blindly answering just the question and nothing more. That's why it is just a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, its a folder permission problem. I think you're trying to extract the src.zip file into a directory that you don't have the right to write into. "C:\Program Files" and their sub directory is owned by administrator.

Try to extract the zip file to somewhere in your home directory. Create a folder there, and extract the zip file into that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions of JDK folder from read-only to modify or try giving full control to the system user/A and then try extracting, you would be able to!